# Lebesgue-integral of functions with countable values

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{A}, \mu)$ be a measure space and let $g: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}\;$ be an integrable function with only countable many values, i.e. $g(\Omega)=\{a_1,a_2,\dots\}$.

I want to know whether $\int g \;d\mu=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i\; \mu(\{\omega \in \Omega|g(\omega)=a_i\})$ holds?

Previous Considerations: $g(\omega)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i \; \mathbb{1}_{A_i}(\omega)$ with $A_i:=\{\omega \in \Omega|g(\omega)=a_i\}$.

($\mathbb{1}_{A_i}$ means the characteristic function)

Hence $\int g\; d\mu=\int g^{+} d\mu \;-\, \int g^{-} \;d\mu=\int \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i \mathbb{1}_{A_i \cap \{g \geq 0\}} \; d\mu \;-\int \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} -a_i \mathbb{1}_{A_i \cap \{g \leq 0\}} \; d\mu \\ \underbrace{=}_{\text{monotone convergence Thm.}} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\int  a_i \mathbb{1}_{A_i \cap \{g \geq 0\}} \; d\mu \;-\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\int  -a_i \mathbb{1}_{A_i \cap \{g \leq 0\}} \; d\mu\\ = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i \mu(A_i \cap \{g\geq0\})+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i \mu(A_i \cap \{g\leq0\})= \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i \mu(A_i )$

Comment: Your proof is fine. In general, if $f$ is integrable and $\langle E_n:n\in\mathbb N\rangle$ is a sequence of pairwise disjoint sets with union $E$, then $\int_E f\, d\mu =\sum_n \int_{E_n} f\, d\mu$. In other words, $A\mapsto \int_A f\, d\mu$ is a measure.

Comment: @Reveillark Thanks for your answer!